# How to install ruby-debug-base19 0.11.25 in railsinstaller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using RailsInstaller in Vista. I am working rottenpotatoes project of Saas Course. So I cloned it from Github. Then I did bundle install. When I ran the command 'rails s' in the directory "hw2_rottenpotatoes" I get an error:

```
[31mCould not find ruby-debug-basw19-0.11.25 in any of the sources [0m
```

[image: This is the error]

Is there any alternate way to install ruby-debug-basw19-0.11.25 ??

UPDATE::
I think rvm is needed!! Hoe to instal rvm when I am using RailsInstaller??

Comment: pry ( http://pry.github.com ) is a good alternative to ruby-debug.

Answer (score 1):

In your Gemfile put:

```
gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```